# mysql insert coma separated string not saving over 948 variables

Tags: mysql

I am using PHP to insert checkbox id's in an array converted to comma separated string for insert into MYSQL. Works, except when over 948 checkboxes. (different amounts for each state)

Why wont it insert over 948 comma separated values?

Here is my PHP code:

```
            $teamsar2 = $_POST['teamarray2'];

         if ($teamsar2){$henry2 = implode(",",$teamsar2);}else{echo '';}

          $query = "UPDATE #__bl_teamcord SET teams='".$henry2."' WHERE s_id=".$sid."  AND u_id=(".intval($_POST['playerid']).")";
                $db->setQuery($query);
                $db->query();
```

Comment: If PHP is used, add PHP tag, if javascript is used, add javascript tag. Are you using an ajax call? Are you using POST or GET? GET might hit it's limit on numbers of characters aloud to transfer.

Answer (score 1):

If it works fine up to a certain limit, I would check your max_allowed_packet size. You may be hitting the limit.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/packet-too-large.html

Comment: This is generally the problem behind weird cases like this.

Comment: Thank you, I am checking it now